# Simple program to find squre root using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Hi I'm new to Python and I wrote a simple program to find the square root of a given number.

```
n = int(input("ENTER YOUR NUMBER: "))
g = n/2
t = 0.0001

def findRoot(x):
    if ((x * x > n - t) and (x * x <= n + t)):
        return x
    else:
        x = (x + n / x) / 2
        findRoot(x)
r = findRoot(g)

print("ROOT OF {} IS {}".format(n, r))
```

`t` is the maximum error.

I know it's easy to use a while loop but I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. I debugged the code and after returning the value `x` (line 7), line 10 runs again resulting a "None" value.

Console output for any `n`, `n > 0` (except 4) is `ROOT OF (Given Number) IS None`

Any idea how to correct the code?

Comment: When you get a `None` return using functions, it is time to check if your function always returns *something*.

Comment: Have you checked, what your script does, with a debugger or [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)? You can see there, why @usr2564301 wrote this comment.

Comment: You can also write `if n - t < x * x <= n + t:`

Comment: @Alexander `if abs(x * x - n) <= t`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to **return** something inside your else block. This should work:

```
def findRoot(x):
    if ((x*x > n - t) and (x*x <= n + t)):
        return x
    else:
        x = (x + n/x)/2
        return findRoot(x)
```

An alternative as suggested by Alexander in the comment below is to remove the `else` altogether, because the code contained within will only ever be reached if we have not already returned inside the `if` block. So this is equivalent:

```
def findRoot(x):
    if ((x*x > n - t) and (x*x <= n + t)):
        return x
    x = (x + n/x)/2
    return findRoot(x)
```

Comment: You don't need the `else`, just remove it and unnest your last two lines.

Comment: Good point, I just made the smallest possible amendment to OP's existing code to make it work, but I'll edit my answer to reflect this.